# PHP Edit Post with Google OpenID

Tags: php, mysql, google-oauth

I'm trying to code an edit post page for my site which posts to itself using a google openid logon, however i just get a blank page, instead of the edit form. Here's the code i'm using:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BQuotes</title>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="votingfiles/voting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="votingfiles/voting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bquotes.me/mystyle-a.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .head_text {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#g-login').bind('click', function (event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // $('#form-id').attr('action', 'google-login.php').trigger('submit');
        alert("Clicked");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="color:#d4ffaa">


    <!-- BQ Edit Post Start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="editPost">
      <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#5FBF00">
        <h1 class="head_text">BQuotes: Edit Statuses</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <?php





          ?>


      </div>



         <?php
          define ('HOSTNAME', 'host');
          define ('USERNAME', 'user');
          define ('PASSWORD', 'pass');
          define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'db');

          $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to MySQL.');

          mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

          $tbl='table';
          $id=$_POST['pid'];

          $query="SELECT * from $tbl WHERE $id=id";
          $result = mysql_query($query);

          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $id=$row['id'];
          $username=$row['username'];
          $message=$row['message'];
          $tag=$row['tag'];



         session_start();
              if($_SESSION['myusername'] != null &&  isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
              echo "<form action='logout.php' method='post' id ='form-logout' data-ajax='false'>
                    <br/><input type='submit' value='Logout'/>";
              echo "</form>";
              echo "<div style='margin-left:20px;'>Logged In As:  ".$_SESSION['myusername']."</div>";

             echo "<form name='post-edit' action='' method='post'>";
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id'].">";
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='username' value=".$row['username'].">";
             echo "<textarea name='message' value=".$row['message'].">";
             echo "<input type='text' name='tag' value=".$row['tag'].">";
             echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Edit!'>";
             echo "</form>";

              }
            else if($_SESSION['myusername'] == null){
              echo "<form action='google-login.php?login=true' method='post' id ='form-id' data-ajax='false'>";    
                 echo "<span class='loginreq'>Login to Edit</span>";           
                echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Login with Google'/>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
            }



          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

          $query = "UPDATE mybq_post_txt_main SET message=$message, tag=$tag WHERE id=$id ";

          $result = mysql_query($query);

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

          echo "Your post has been edited to:";<br>
          echo $row['message'];
          echo $row['tag'];
          }

          mysql_free_result($result);
          mysql_close();

          }

        ?>



        <a href='mybq-index.php'>Home</a>


      </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated. (never mind the PHP SQL statements, I will convert them to PDO later).

Comment: While we're "never minding", `$id=$_POST['pid'];` should be adjusted later to sanitize data and `session_start` after content has been echoed is useless (session headers already sent)... Yes, a bit snippy here, but "I'll do it better later" just irritates me.  As the saying goes, "Takes less time to do it right than do it over."

Comment: ok noted Jeremy. Thanks. This was just old code i was working with and I wanted functionality first. :-)

Comment: What is the result from the database query? If that returns 0 rows, neither form displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265115/mysql-error-on-edit-post-submit) is the code that worked (The Full code below the snippet).
The initial bug was the line break ( `<br>` ) after the "your post has been edited to:" which was not properly formatted for php.
The other bugs were relating the $_GET variable properly, wrong table name, and wrong looping of the initial 'while' condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT * from $tbl WHERE $id=id";
```

Should be

```
$query="SELECT * from $tbl WHERE id=$id";
```

(i.e. flip around the "id" to put the SQL column first and your PHP variable second)

Not sure if that will fix everything, but that was the first thing that jumped out at me.

Comment: Thank You Josh, applied; but still noluck :-(

Comment: Actually it works both ways. `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 3 = id`.

Comment: Hrm, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you at least want the login form to show up if not logged in yet. If so, change:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

...

}
```

To this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

...

//}
```

I'm assuming the query is only intended to return either 1 or 0 rows, so no need for loop anyway.

I have the closing braced rem'd out to clarify that it needs to be taken out of the operating code. You can just delete it.

The forms in your code are within the WHILE mysql_fetch_array loop, so when no user record is found neither form gets a chance to display.

Comment: Done that BK, no luck. and with regard to your earlier question of if the query is returning rows, i assume of course, because the posts are there...

Comment: What does `print_r($_SESSION['myusername'])` give you if you put that immediately after `session_start();`?

Comment: So `$_SESSION['myusername']` is not set. Try putting `$_SESSION['myusername'] = 'test';` immediately after `session_start();` as a test to see if your edit form shows up;

Comment: i'm afraid still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving session_start() to the top of your page?  You generally want to call this before anything else is sent to the browser.  Above the HTML tag, probably.