# MySQL Error on Edit Post Submit

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to fix the error in my earlier post wrt edit form not showing.
Now edit form shows, but when i try to update (submit), i get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

FF is the code snippet i used:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = mysql_real_escape_string(".$row['message'].") WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "Your post has been edited to:", "<br>";
        echo $row['message'];
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();

}
```

Kindly Help. Thanks!

As Per @Fred-ii and @jeroen 's request, here is the full code:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BQuotes</title>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="votingfiles/voting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="votingfiles/voting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bquotes.me/mystyle-a.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .head_text {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#g-login').bind('click', function (event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // $('#form-id').attr('action', 'google-login.php').trigger('submit');
        alert("Clicked");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="color:#d4ffaa">


    <!-- BQ Edit Post Start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="edit-post">
      <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#5FBF00">
        <h1 class="head_text">BQuotes</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">




      </div>



         <?php




         session_start();

              if($_SESSION['myusername'] != null &&  isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
              echo "<form action='logout.php' method='post' id ='form-logout' data-ajax='false'>
                    <br/><input type='submit' value='Logout'/>";
              echo "</form>";
              echo "<div style='margin-left:1px;'>Logged In As:  ".$_SESSION['myusername']."</div>";



          define ('HOSTNAME', 'xxxx');
          define ('USERNAME', 'xxxx');
          define ('PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
          define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'xxxx');

          $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to MySQL.');

          mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

          $tbl='xxxx';
          $id=$_GET['pid'];


          $query="SELECT * from $tbl WHERE id = ".$_GET['pid']." ";


          $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          /*$id=$row['id'];
          $username=$row['username'];
          $message=$row['message'];
          $tag=$row['tag'];*/



             echo "<form name='edit-post' action='' method='post'>";
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$row['id'].">";
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='username' value=".$row['username'].">";
             echo "Status: <textarea name='message'>".$row['message']."</textarea>";
             //echo "Tag: <textarea rows='1' name='tag'>".$row['tag']."</textarea>";
             echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
             echo "</form>";


          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {         

          echo $row['id'];
          $tbl = 'xxxx';           
          $query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = ".mysql_real_escape_string($row['message'])." WHERE id =".$row['id']." ";

          $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());


          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

          echo "Your post has been edited to:", "<br>";
          echo $row['message'];
          //echo $row['tag'];
          }

          mysql_free_result($result);
          mysql_close();

          }

              }
              }
            else if($_SESSION['myusername'] == null){
              echo "<form action='google-login.php?login=true' method='post' id ='form-id' data-ajax='false'>";    
                 echo "<span class='loginreq'>Login to Edit</span>";           
                echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Login with Google'/>";
                echo "</form>";
            }




          /*
          <?php
          $id2=$_POST['id'];
          $username2=$_POST['username'];
          $message2=$_POST['message'];
          $tag2=$_POST['tag'];
          */



        ?>



        <a href='mybq-index.php'>Home</a>


      </div>


  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: maybe mysql_real_escape_string should be evaluated in php and not by the MySQL backend, which I doubt knows anything about mysql_* functions.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and show us more code including HTML form and DB connection code, while replacing DB credentials with `xxx`.

Comment: Read my answer and the comments below it. For one you are not quoting the value of `message` in the `UPDATE` statement. Strings need to be quoted when you inject them directly in an sql statement.

Comment: Use `var_dump($_GET['pid']);` right after `$id=$_GET['pid'];` to make sure there is indeed a set `pid`. Plus, use `var_dump();` and/or `print_r();` for other variables, such as your query `var_dump($query);` to see what's going through (or not).

Comment: Or `var_dump($id);` instead of `var_dump($_GET['pid']);`

Comment: I have replaced echo $row['id']; with var_dump($id); still does not display anything. (see @Jens comment below).

Comment: By the way, here's the result of the error_reporting, although i feel the problem is with the missing ['id']: Notice: Undefined index: pid in /path/edit-post.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined index: pid in /path/edit-post.php on line 76

Comment: Either you use a hidden field with `name="pid"` and query it from there, or it seems like you're trying pull the `pid` from your query, so try `WHERE id = ".$id." ";` or `WHERE id = '".$id."' ";` or something like that, since you've assigned a `$id` variable to it.

Comment: @Fred-ii , var_dump($_GET['pid']); gives ' string(3) "419" ' , so i'm thinking i may have assigned a string to the 'id' in the query?

Comment: What about `var_dump($id);` after `$query="SELECT * from....`? what results do you get?

Comment: ' string(3) "419" ' also

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed It!
The problem was having the form post to itself, so i created a new action file (edit-post-act.php) thus:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BQuotes</title>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="votingfiles/voting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="votingfiles/voting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bquotes.me/mystyle-a.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .head_text {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#g-login').bind('click', function (event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // $('#form-id').attr('action', 'google-login.php').trigger('submit');
        alert("Clicked");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="color:#d4ffaa">


    <!-- BQ Edit Post Act Start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="edit-post-act">
      <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#5FBF00">
        <h1 class="head_text">BQuotes</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">




      </div>



         <?php




         session_start();

              if($_SESSION['myusername'] != null &&  isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
              echo "<form action='logout.php' method='post' id ='form-logout' data-ajax='false'>
                    <br/><input type='submit' value='Logout'/>";
              echo "</form>";
              echo "<div style='margin-left:1px;'>Logged In As:  ".$_SESSION['myusername']."</div>";


          $id2=$_POST['id'];
          $username2=$_POST['username'];
          $message2=$_POST['message'];
          $tag2=$_POST['tag'];

          define ('HOSTNAME', 'xxxx');
          define ('USERNAME', 'xxxx');
          define ('PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
          define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'xxxx');

          $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to MySQL.');

          mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);


          $tbl = 'xxxx';           
          $query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = '$message2' WHERE id = '$id2' ";

          $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());




          echo "Your post has been edited to:", "<br>";
          echo $message2;


          mysql_free_result($result);
          mysql_close();

          }
            else if($_SESSION['myusername'] == null){
              echo "<form action='google-login.php?login=true' method='post' id ='form-id' data-ajax='false'>";    
                 echo "<span class='loginreq'>Login to Edit</span>";           
                echo "<br/><input type='submit' value='Login with Google'/>";
                echo "</form>";
            }

            ?>

        <a href='mybq-index.php'>Home</a>


      </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you, Everyone! Cc: @Fred-ii , @jeroen

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is a php function, not a mysql function.

So the syntax would be:

```
$query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($row['message']) . "' WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ";
```

But you should really switch to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: @adeoba Have you done a `var_dump()` of the generated sql statement? Possibly the table name needs to be quoted in backticks or the id needs to be quoted depending on the type of column. Also note the single quotes around the `message` value.

Comment: @jeroen Maybe OP's `id`'s aren't `int`s, and should probably use `WHERE id = '".$row['id']."' ";` (?)

Comment: @jeroen I hadn't reloaded ;-) well, it's up to the OP to either get back here, or to further his/her troubleshooting. Error seems to be consistent with others' answers. I fear something else; connection type maybe? Who knows.

Comment: @jeroen Check out OP's [**other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24027918/) is using `$tbl='table';` so, hard to say if that is still the same variable is using. Plus, another question mentions the use of PDO. This one's a classic "can of worms". Plus, just as you stated above about backtick'ing the `$tbl` variable.

Comment: My id type is int(10). My message type is varchar(140), so i'm thinking that's not the problem.. Please give me a little while to get back on others.

Comment: @adeoba If you are using the same code as in [**your other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24027918/) where you are using `$tbl='table';` then either rename your table name, or use backticks around your `$tbl` variable inside your query, because `table` is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). I think that everyone has done more than enough to try and solve the problem. I posted a comment under your question with no response. Post your FULL code, for everything. We are not behind your computer, you are. I have voted to close till then.

Comment: @adeoba I can understand that; believe me, I do. Yet, when you post a question that doesn't hold enough details, it's hard for everyone to pinpoint where the problem is. I posted my original comment almost a 1/2 hour ago under your question to post your full code, including the HTML form and DB credentials, while replacing those with `xxx`. As I mentioned in a comment above about your use of `$tbl='table';` in your other question. We don't know what you're using for a variable now. It could be one of many things. If there's ever a next time and we like to help, do post as much info as you can.

Comment: @adeoba Thanks for that. However, I know I said to replace credentials with `xxx` but is this your actual table name `$tbl='xxxx';` (xxxx)? It's important that we know.

Comment: @Fred-ii xxxx is not my actual table name!

Comment: @adeoba What is your table name then? Plus, I've placed another comment under your question.

Answer (score 0):

once try this way

```
$query = "UPDATE $tbl SET 
          message = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['message'])."'
           WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ";
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding the fact you are using the mysql_ functions and people love to nagg you about that.

Try making life a little simpler for yourself and do this:

```
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($row['message']) 
$query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = '$msg' WHERE id = {$row['id']}";
```

Or ever this

```
 $query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = '" . 
           mysql_real_escape_string($row['message']) . 
          "' WHERE id = {$row['id']}";
```

Then you would probably have spotted that you missed the single quotes around the text field called `message`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change to this updatestatement:

```
 $query = "UPDATE $tbl SET message = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['message'])."' WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ";
```

Comment: @adeoba and `$row['id']` is not empty?

Comment: @adeoba Then it is not a problem with the query. if id is blank then you can`t make an update. You shold find out why the `$row['id']` is not filled.

Comment: I'm thinking that's what I have to work on. Will revert.